# Dual subfactor and commutant

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $(N  \subset M)$ be a subfactor and  $N  \subset M \subset M_1$ the basic construction.

**Question**: Is $(M \subset M_1) \simeq (M' \subset N')$? Else in which generic case it's true?
What's the proof?

Comment: I assume you want something beyond the obvious anti-isomorphism given by $J_M$?

Comment: @MartinArgerami: I'm looking for the most general case possible giving an isomorphism of subfactors (in fact, planar algebra equivalence would be enough for me). Nevertheless, a large generic case would be nice.

Comment: @MartinArgerami: A von Neumann algebra is anti-isomorphic to its opposite, but not isomorphic to it in general, isn't it? Do you have an example of factor not isomorphic to its opposite? Anyway "being isomorphic to its opposite" for the factors seems to be the good assumption for the isomorphism of subfactors, but it's not clear to me if it's necessary for the planar algebra equivalence.

Comment: @MartinArgerami: I've found the following paper of Alain Connes: [A Factor not Anti-Isomorphic to itself](http://blms.oxfordjournals.org/content/7/2/171.abstract). The example of Alain is a type ${\rm III}$ factor.  I don't know yet if there is an example of type ${\rm II}_1$.

Comment: There is. Some information here and its references: http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?arg3=&co4=AND&co5=AND&co6=AND&co7=AND&dr=all&pg4=AUCN&pg5=TI&pg6=PC&pg7=ALLF&pg8=ET&review_format=html&s4=viola%2C%20maria%20grazia&s5=&s6=&s7=&s8=All&vfpref=html&yearRangeFirst=&yearRangeSecond=&yrop=eq&r=3&mx-pid=2097021  I still don't think that answers your question, though.

Comment: @MartinArgerami: Thank you. I've no access to mathscinet at home. Could you give me the title of the paper? Anyway, could you develop your last sentence?

Comment: "On a subfactor construction of a factor non-antisomorphic to itself", by Maria Grazia Viola. It cites other work of Jones, too. I don't think it addresses your question, because as far as I can tell, a factor can be not anti-isomorphic to itself and still satisfy the isomorphism you are looking for. As I said, $M\subset M_1$ is always anti-isomorphic to $M'\subset N'$ via $J_M\cdot J_M$.

Comment: @MartinArgerami: It seems depend to what's the definition of isomorphism of subfactors, if it's "$(A \subset B) \sim (C \subset D) \Leftrightarrow \exists \phi \in Iso(B,D) \ :   \ \phi(A) = C$ "  then it can't work if the factors are not anti-isomorphic to itself; but now if the definition is "to have the same planar algebra" then I don't know.

Comment: Yes, but in your question you have $M'$ on the right had side, not $M$. Every factor represented standarly is anti-isomorphic to its commutant.

Comment: @MartinArgerami: I don't understand, because if such an isomorphism $\phi$ exists, then $\phi(M) = M'$ and so $M$ is isomorphic to its commutant. If $M$ is not anti-isomorphic to itself, then it can't be isomorphic to its commutant.

Comment: When represented standardly, **every** factor is isomorphic to its commutant. I cannot see the relation with $M$ being anti-isomorphic to itself or not.

Comment: @MartinArgerami: in your previous comment you wrote << Every factor represented standarly is **anti**-isomorphic to its commutant >> and now you write << When represented standardly, every factor is isomorphic to its commutant >>. Which one is the right sentence?

Comment: "anti-isomorphic" is what it should have said.

Comment: @MartinArgerami: ok so for having $M$ isomorphic to its commutant, (because it's already anti-isomorphic to its commutant) it's necessary for $M$ to be anti-isomorphic to itself.

Comment: Yes, now I see it. My bad.